# Call Variable from Component in Helper.js

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an attribute declared in component.

```
<aura:attribute name="ifTrue" type="Boolean" default="False" description="Boolean  show records." />
```

I am setting the value to it from a function in helper.js

```
component.set('v.ifTrue', searchItem.includes('FTP'));
```

Now I'm trying to access the value from component. I alreday set value to true and am expecting to see "True" when I use console.log in helper in other function.

```
 console.log('ifTrue Value>>:'+{!ifTrue});
```

It gives me format issues while debugging. I tried other formats like `{!V.ifTrue}`, `"{!v.ifTrue}"`, `ifTrue` etc. But I get errors.

What is the correct format to access attribute on helper. When I use `"{!v.ifTrue}"` similar to in `component.set();`, it gives me the string `{!v.ifTrue}` in debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value like so

```
console.log('v.ifTrue' + component.get("v.ifTrue"));
```

Or more verbose

```
var trueValue = component.get("v.ifTrue");
console.log("v.ifTrue " + trueValue);
```